# Magento 2 category sidebar configuration

Tags: magento2, sidebar

I'm using magento 2 and I would like to configure my sidebar from the category page , for example , now in my sidebar I have also Compare products and My whish list , and I would like to get rid of them from there. There is any option in the admin panel to do that , or which is the file to edit so I can hide the code for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add below code to your theme `default.xml` file and remove sidebar wishlist and compare product block using xml.

```
<referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
```

Remove cache and check.

Comment: Thank you again for your support @Rakesh ! It works fine ! Do you have any ideea how I might do this also : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113352/magento-2-color-and-size-visual-on-the-category-sidebar ?